# FileUpload not working inside Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I know this question is asked many times here but I just started android development so getting confused to apply those solutions. With my code FileUpload option not working. It's not opening file choosing dialogue box. Please help me

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> // variables for camera and choosing files methods
> private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
> private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
> private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
> // the same for Android 5.0 methods only
> private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
> private String mCameraPhotoPath;
> private class DefaultWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
>     @Override
>     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
>         view.loadUrl(url);
>         return true;
>     }
> }
>   @Override
>  public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     // code for all versions except of Lollipop
>     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
>         if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
>             if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
>                 return;
>             }
>             Uri result=null;
>             try{
>                 if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
>                     result = null;
>                 } else {
>                     // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
>                     result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
>                 }
>             }
>             catch(Exception e) {
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             }
>             mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
>             mUploadMessage = null;
>         }
>     } // end of code for all versions except of Lollipop
>     // start of code for Lollipop only
>     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
>         if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
>             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>             return;
>         }
>         Uri[] results = null;
>         // check that the response is a good one
>         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
>             if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
>                 // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
>                 if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
>                     results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
>                 }
>             } else {
>                 String dataString = data.getDataString();
>                 if (dataString != null) {
>                     results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};}
>                 }
>         }
>     mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
>         mFilePathCallback = null;
>     } // end of code for Lollipop only  
>    }
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>         WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
>         WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
>         webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
>         webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
>         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>         webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
>         webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
>         webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
>         webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
>        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new DefaultWebViewClient() );
>      mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
>         {
>             // for Lollipop, all in one
>             public boolean onShowFileChooser(
>                     WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
>                     WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
>                 if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
>                     mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
>                 }
>                 mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
>                 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
>                 if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
>              File photoFile = null;
>                     try {
>                         photoFile = createImageFile();
>                         takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
>                     } catch (IOException ex) {
>                         // Error occurred while creating the File
>                         Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
>                     }
>                     if (photoFile != null) {
>                         mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
>                     takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
>                                 Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
>                     } else {
>                         takePictureIntent = null;
>                     }
>                 }
>                 Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);              contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
>                 contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
>                 Intent[] intentArray;
>                 if (takePictureIntent != null) {
>                     intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
>                 } else {
>                     intentArray = new Intent[0];
>                 }
>                 Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
>                 chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
>                 chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Choose");
>                 chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
>                 startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
>                 return true;
>             }
>             private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
>                 File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");
>                 if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
>                     imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
>                 }
>                 // create an image file name
>                 imageStorageDir  = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
>                 return imageStorageDir;
>             }
>             // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
>             public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
>                 mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
>                 try {
>                     File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");
>                     if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
>                         imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
>                     }
>                     File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
>                     mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); // save to the private variable
>                     final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
>                     captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
>                     // captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
>                     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
>                     i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
>                     i.setType("*/*");
>                     Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose");
>                 chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});
>                     startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
>                 } catch (Exception e) {
>                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 }
>             }
>             // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
>             public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
>                 openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
>             }
>             // openFileChooser for other Android versions
>         /* may not work on KitKat due to lack of implementation of openFileChooser() or onShowFileChooser()
>            https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220
>            however newer versions of KitKat fixed it on some devices */
>             public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
>                 openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
>             }
>         });
>         mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
>     }
> ```

Comment: Both are different code or alternative of each other?

Comment: no, you need to use both. openfilechooser should be called , and then the file chosen u have to recieve onactivityresult.

Comment: And since I just started. Where do I need to put this code in side main activity class?

Comment: yes. Also check your permission in maifest, where you allow <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114358/discussion-between-stone-and-user3278732).

Answer (score 0):

Check the app permissions in Emulator Application > Settings.